# Numbers smaller than realmin

Tags: matlab, precision

Today I stumbled onto this plain problem in Matlab:

```
>> 1/(10^309)

ans =

     0
```

and everything is fine. Now I type:

```
>> 0.0001/(10^308)

ans =

    9.999999999984653e-313
```

and get very confused. Wasn't the smallest number possible in Matlab `realmin=2.225073858507201e-308`? Why is the above output not giving `0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `help realmin`, it says: "REALMIN Smallest positive normalized floating point number."

A normalized floating point number has no leading zeros in the significand - so something like 1.123 * 10^-10. If the significand has leading zeros, like 0.0001 * 10^-10, then it is [denormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal).

I think `eps(0)` gives the smallest denormal number available in Matlab.

Answer (score 6):

[`realmin`](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/realmin.html) returns the smallest positive **normalized** floating-point number in IEEE double precision.

There are smaller positive [**denormal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal) floating point numbers. Have a look at “[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf)”.

You might be more interested in [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html) that returns the  smallest increment between distinct numbers.